# Difference between 때 and 시간

Tags: vocabulary, translation, meaning, word-usage

What is the the difference between 때 and 시간 ? I read they both mean time, trying to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both common terms meaning "time" with similar and different usages.

때:

1. at the time (of certain event, occurrence, etc); when (in -는/(으)ㄹ/던 때 form).
2. a particular moment or short duration in time; (certain) *hour(s)*.
3. opportune time; opportunity or opening.

시간:

1. time in general, as a concept of a medium.
2. any (long or short) duration of time (often viewed as a limited resource).
3. #2 sense of 때.

Examples:

1. 몸이 너무 피곤할 때는 자는 게 제일이다 = When you're very tired, good sleep is the best thing.
2. 점심 때에 만나자 = Let's meet around lunch time.
3. 모든 일에는 때가 있다 = There is a (right) time for everything.

---

1. "존재와 시간" = *Being and Time* (a book on philosophy).
2. 이것은 시간이 많이 걸리는 작업이다 = This is a task that requires a lot of time.
3. 아침 시간에는/때에는 길이 많이 붐빈다 = The roads get crowded in morning hours.